# Sort function with customizable comparision function

Tags: sorting, scheme, lisp, racket

After writing:

```
(define (sort-asc l)
  (cond ((eq? l '()) '())
        ((eq? (cdr l) '()) (list (car l)))
        ((< (car l) (cadr l)) (cons (car l) (sort-asc (cdr l)) ))
        (else (cons (cadr l) (sort-asc (cons (car l) (cddr l)) )))))
```

How do you write a function that can additionally take a comparison function as a parameter?

Tried:

```
(define (sort-f l f)
  (cond ((eq? l '()) '())
        ((eq? (cdr l) '()) (list (car l)))
        ((lambda ()(f (car l) (cadr l))) (cons (car l) (sort-f (cdr l) f)))
        (else (cons (cadr l) (sort-f (cons (car l) (cddr l)) f)))))
```

But `(sort-f '(4 3 8 2 5) <)` returns the same list.
p.s. Is there any way to make this code look more elegant by somehow rewriting of all the `car`'s, `cadr`'s and `cdr`'s?

Comment: I don't think your `SORT-ASC` works either. You should probably try something like [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) or [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). Anyway, to use the function passed as an argument you can just do `(F ARG1 ARG2)`. No need for that `LAMBDA`.

Comment: @jkiiski Not just "no need for that `lambda`", but that it actively causes the code to not work since `lambda` returns a procedure, which is always truthy.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Maybe jkiiski thought that X10D had meant `(cond ... (((lambda () (f (car l) (cadr l)))) ...)`, which would have worked.

Comment: Apart from the spurious (and wrong) `lambda`, you could make this look a lot better by using `first` etc.  I forget if Scheme has them, but they are easy to define if not.

Comment: @tfb `first`, `second`, etc. are built into Racket. They're also available in SRFI 1 for other Scheme implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Your third `cond` branch condition should be `(f (car l) (cadr l))`, not `(lambda () ...)`. The `lambda` expression returns a procedure (which is not invoked), and since all procedures are truthy, the fourth (`else`) branch is never reached.

That is,

```
((lambda ()(f (car l) (cadr l))) (cons (car l) (sort-f (cdr l) f)))
```

should be

```
((f (car l) (cadr l)) (cons (car l) (sort-f (cdr l) f)))
```

Comment: I guess `((lambda () (f (car l) (cadr l)))` would work, but that is an awful lot of extra typing for `(f (car l) (cadr l))`, as well as being much less readable.